# Pyinstaller on windows fills up limited home dir space and crashes with No space left on device

Tags: windows, pyinstaller

I am trying to use Pyinstaller on windows. Pyinstaller uses a bin cache that's located at %appdata%/pyinstaller on Windows. In my corporate environment, the space for the home dir is very limited, so pyinstaller quickly fills it up and then fails with "No space left on device".
Is there any way to change the location of the cache or work around it? I did not find any option to achieve that in the docs or man pages.